# How can I announce a result I think is new and groundbreaking without being off-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-hold-questions

So, a few days ago I posted a result I had achieved about the limit of a complex infinite sum.
I wanted to know if my finding was new (not discovered before), but the post was put on hold as off-topic, leaving me without an answer.
It seems for the real part of the limit a result was already known (not sure if for all cases), but the imaginary part apparently is not known.

How can I announce a new result in the form of a question? Is it allowed at all?

Comment: If you have to think about how to turn what you want to post into a question, it probably doesn't belong on a Q&A site like this.

Answer (score 21):

You simply don't. The scope of this site is not to announce new results. It's also not a good idea to do it here, it will be buried under a deluge of homework questions.

Write it up and submit it to the relevant journal. Post it to arXiv. Publish it on your blog. Do it on a platform where people can refer and cite your work.

But don't use this website as a platform for announcing new results, groundbreaking or otherwise.